# Does 64 bit calling convention make a difference to cost of recursive algorithms

Tags: performance, recursion, 64-bit

When I was taught computer science there was some discussion as to the cost of recursion, because of the function call overhead, and how to convert to something more efficient. E.g., to iteration, seehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration?rq=1, or turning a naturally recursive algorithm into an iterative one: e.g. running an algorithm bottom up rather than top down.

One of the interesting things about 64 bit architectures is the support for passing more parameters to and fro using registers. To [quote Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf)

> It is more efficient to use registers for transferring parameters to a function and for receiving 
>   the return value than to store these values on the stack... In 64-bit systems, the use of registers for parameter transfer is standardized. All systems use registers for return values if the returned object fits into the registers that are assigned for this purpose

Does this mean that I don't need to worry so much about the cost of recursive function calls on 64 bit architectures?

Comment: You worry a bit less.  It is no panacea.

Comment: The reasons why 64-bit programs require more stack memory - http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0069/

Comment: @AndreyCpp v interesting article (applying to all functions not just recursive ones) thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the parameters are passed in registers, the function will need to save some state on the stack as it recurses. If any of that state is a pointer, you've doubled the space requirements. This could potentially halve the maximum recursion depth you can achieve for a given stack size.

Answer (score 0):

Passing parameters in registers won't change memory consumption properties of the algorithm, it will still require the same stack space. Calling conventions fix registers used for every positional parameter, and obviously the same register cannot be used to pass the different value deeper down the call stack, so compiler will have to spill it into memory.

Comment: If I've understood you rightly, you're saying, for example, that if we have `f(x,y)` which recursively calls `f(g(x),h(y))` and `f(g'(x),h'(y))`, then we couldn't use registers P and Q for the parameters `x` and `y`, because if we did so and made the first call to `f` without spilling `x` / `y` or `g'(x)` / `h'(y)` to memory, we wouldn't be able to make the second call to `f`. That's a good point! However I'm not sure this means recursive parameters can _never_ be in registers. E.g. `f(x,y,c,k)`, where `c`, `k` are constants. Here am I right in thinking that `c` and `k` can be in registers?